# Trying to open project in xCode 4

Tags: xcode4

I try to open 'Reachability' example from Apple site in xCode4. I am clicking on Reachability.xcodeproj and getting only warning 'No Editor'. What could it mean and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say, getting only warning 'No Editor', you mean you are getting "No Editor" message in editor view pane? If yes, please select e file to view in editor from Project Navigator (Cmd + 1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same issue, Pressing CMD-1 fixed it for me.